# Access to HttpServletContext or session from javax.ws.rs.core.Feature

Tags: java, jersey

**Context**

I am migrating an old legacy jersey application to use a more up-to-date version(2.27).

The application uses jetty servlet to process the authentication and set login information inside the HttpSession.

Then we have some plugins that use jersey and receive the authentication token from an annotation (@SdnUser).

The application is big, and I'd like to avoid the migration process of the authentication method.

**Before the migration**

I was using an abstract binder linked to an AbstractValueFactoryProvider that provided an AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory.

This AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory gave me access to a RessourceContext where I could get the HttpSession.

```
    private static final class IdentityParamValueFactory extends AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory<UserManagement.User> {

        private final UserManagement userManagement;
        @Context
        private ResourceContext context;

        public IdentityParamValueFactory(final UserManagement userManagement) {
            this.userManagement = userManagement;
        }

        public UserManagement.User provide() {
            final HttpServletRequest request = context.getResource(HttpServletRequest.class);
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            //... code ommited
    }
```

**Now**

I have adapted the code to use a feature and an abstract binder :

```
public class UserBinder implements Feature {

    private final UserManagement userManagement;

    public UserBinder(final UserManagement userManagement) {
        this.userManagement = userManagement;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean configure(final FeatureContext context) {
        context.register(new AbstractBinder() {

            @Context
            private HttpServletRequest webRequest;

            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                UserValueParamProvider userValueParamProvider = new UserValueParamProvider(userManagement, webRequest);
                bind(userValueParamProvider)
                        .to(ValueParamProvider.class)
                        .in(RequestScoped.class);
            }
        });

        return true;
    }

    public static class UserValueParamProvider implements ValueParamProvider {

        // SLF4J Logger
        private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserBinder.class);

        private final UserManagement userManagement;

        private HttpServletRequest webRequest;

        private UserValueParamProvider(final UserManagement userManagement, HttpServletRequest webRequest) {
            this.userManagement = userManagement;
            this.webRequest = webRequest;
        }

        @Override
        public Function<ContainerRequest, UserManagement.User> getValueProvider(final Parameter parameter) {
            if (parameter.getRawType().equals(UserManagement.User.class)
                    && parameter.isAnnotationPresent(SdnUser.class)) {
                return context -> {
                    ContainerRequest containerRequest = (ContainerRequest) context.getRequest();
                    // The next line is invalid, as the request is a ContainerRequest not an HttpServletRequest
                    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getRequest();
                    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
// ... code ommited
```

But the functional return of getValueProvider has no context injection, and I cannot reach the HttpSession.

How can I access the HttpSession inside my annotation binder ?

Comment: Could you try to move a field with @Context annotation up on the code execution chain. I meant to pass it as a parameter into UserBinder constructor and place another field with the annotation in tbr place where you call your Binder.

Comment: As I understand, this will not work (I have tested it anyway and that's not working), because the UserBinder are created at the start of the application, and the injection of context is done by request.

Comment: Right, maybe there is way to pass WebRequest from your servlet into the code where it is needed

Comment: Please, add #java hashtag to your question.

Comment: Inject `javax.inject.Provider<HttpServletRequest>`. Pass the provider into the Function constructor and call `get()` in the `Funtion#apply()` method. `Provider` is used for lazy retrieval. You need to use it in this case because there is no request on startup.

Comment: I love you, this is perfectly working, you can post an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject `javax.inject.Provider<HttpServletRequest>`. Pass the provider into the `Function` constructor and call `provider.get()` in the `Funtion#apply()` method. [`Provider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/inject/Provider.html) is used for lazy retrieval. You need to use it in this case because there is no request on startup.